# Is manually simulating the effects of the delete operator in C++ formally illegal?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I realise this is ill-advised, and I'm not proposing to do it, but I'm curious as to whether the following is actually formally illegal:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    ~X()
    {
        std::cout << "~X()\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    X *x = new X;
    //delete x;
    x->~X();
    ::operator delete(x);
    return 0;
}
```

It's my understanding that `delete x;` is equivalent to invoking the destructor and then calling `::operator delete(x);`, but is it legal for me to do that manually according to the standard? I know this is a valid thing to when using placement new, but what about in the non-placement case? My hunch is that it might be illegal because `delete` (and not `operator delete`) has to be performed for each `new`, but I'd be interested to know for sure.

Comment: are you asking whether `delete x;` is equivalent to invoking destructor and then `operator delete(x);` for *this particular code sample*, or *in general*?

Comment: @Ben: In this particular code sample -- but I'm also interested in the general case (for which I now assume the answer is no).

Comment: Glad I asked this question -- there's actually a lot more to the answer than I was imagining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is not standard compliant.  Nowhere in the standard (that I'm aware of) does it say that the operand of `delete p;` is passed directly to the deallocation function, and for `delete []` it almost certainly **isn't** passed through unchanged.

It will probably work on all practical implementations, however.

For certain, you shouldn't be calling the global deallocation function explicitly.  It's fine in your example, which doesn't have user-defined allocation and deallocation functions, but not in the general case (actually, is there any syntax for calling the class-specific deallocation function if it exists, and the global one otherwise?).

Also, in the general case, the pointer passed to the deallocation function is definitely not the operand of delete.  Consider:

```
struct A
{
  virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B1 : virtual A {};

struct B2 : virtual A {};

struct B3 : virtual A {};

struct D : virtual B1, virtual B2, virtual B3 {};

struct E : virtual B1, virtual D {};

int main( void )
{
  B3* p = new D();
  p->~B3(); // should be ok, calling virtually
  operator delete(p); // definitely NOT OK

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, I think I'm definitely in agreement on the "shouldn't" aspect of it all :) The guys in comp.lang.c++ also mentioned that user-defined `operator new` and `operator delete` would cause problems, so it seems like a dumb thing to do even if it were legal. As to the syntax question -- I know you can call `T::operator delete` to get T's class-specific one provided it exists. There may well be some template metaprogramming one can do to make sure the global one is called otherwise, but I'm not an expert on that. It's probably an SFINAE thing of some sort if it is possible I'd guess.

Comment: "_I'm pretty sure that this is not standard compliant._" Do you mean that the **specific code** in the question is not guaranteed to work? Do you mean that `new X` may not call `operator new (sizeof (X))`?

Comment: @curiousguy; I mean that `new X` is allowed to have other side effects besides calling the allocation function and the constructor, which require a later matching delete expression.

Comment: "_actually, is there any syntax for calling the class-specific deallocation function if it exists_" I am pretty sure this one is not doable.

Comment: "_allowed to have other side effects_" like what? allowed where? "_which **require** a later matching delete expression_" I am not sure what this could mean. Leaking memory?

Comment: @curiousguy: That's the most likely outcome, but it could have stored a pointer in some list, and if the memory gets reused without that pointer being removed, there could be any sort of trouble.  Although I do believe the standard specifically allows ending an object's lifetime by reusing its memory, so implementations are probably somewhat restricted here.

Comment: I don't see anything in the standard that makes `new`/`delete` special. Where does it say that `new`/`delete` must be paired?

Comment: @curiousguy: section `5.3.5`: "The *elete-expression* operator destroys a most derived object (1.8) or array created by a *new-expression*."  And then goes on to say that `delete` on a non-null pointer acquired any other way is undefined behavior.  Obviously you can just call `new` and never call `delete` (for a small number of objects intended to live until the process terminates).  The question is whether it's legal to call an `operator delete()` deallocation function on a pointer you didn't get by calling `operator new()` directly

Comment: I don't see a formal requirement here.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going this way, you should replace

```
X *x = new X;
```

by

```
X* x = static_cast<X*>(::operator new(sizeof(X)));

try { new(x) X; }
catch (...) { ::operator delete(x); throw; }
```

which should be (please correct me if I'm wrong) consistant with your destruction approach, and pretty much equivalent in functionality to `new`.

Comment: Thanks - that's using placement new though (I know that's valid). I was more curious as to whether it was illegal to mix and match the two.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is exactly what `new` does - unless there is some `new` overloading going on.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you don't invoke undefined behaviour if you call the destructor and free the memory.

Comment: Thanks -- it's not the definitive answer I was looking for, but I appreciate the opinion. I've asked this on comp.lang.c++ in case anyone can enlighten me with chapter & verse from the standard.

Comment: Call the destructor and free the memory, yes.  But you have to free the right memory by calling the right deallocation function *and* passing the right pointer.  Which is a LOT more complicated in the general case, than the code in this question suggests.

Answer (score 1):

@StuartGolodetz

Answer, *and* reply to a comment

> There may well be some template metaprogramming one can do to make sure the global one is called otherwise, but I'm not an expert on that. It's probably an SFINAE thing of some sort if it is possible I'd guess.

```
struct B {
    virtual ~B();
};

struct D : B {
    operator new (size_t);
    operator delete (void*);
};

B *p = new D;

decltype(typeid(*p))::operator delete (...); // hypothetical C++++
```

Meta this!

Comment: This uses the static type of `*p`, which is `B`, right?  And thus calls the wrong deallocator?  In fact it shouldn't even compile, because `B` has no member `operator delete`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Hum, you took it literally? `*p::` that's not even C++!

Comment: I suppose not, but `decltype(*p)::` is.

Comment: @BenVoigt 1) `T::operator delete` would probably not be well-formed for a type `T` without an `operator delete`. 2) The "regular expression" `(T::|::)operator delete` will perhaps not compile either. 3) `decltype(*p)` is `B`, I don't want to call either the non-existent `B::operator delete` or `::operator delete`, but `D::operator delete`. 4) Do you think `decltype(typeid(*p))::operator delete` would work?

Comment: 1) Said that in my comment, and my answer.  2) I wouldn't expect that to compile, asked in my answer for a correct syntax.  3) Said that in my comment and my answer. 4) No.  `decltype(typeid)` is `type_info` (or maybe some `const` reference variation thereon)

Answer (score 0):

I thought that

```
::operator delete(x);
```

is the same as

```
delete x;
```

if the `delete` method is not overridden by X?

Comment: It's not.  The `delete` operator calls the destructor, if the pointer is not null, and then calls the deallocation function, if the pointer is not null and maybe even if it is.  The parameter passed to the deallocation function is not specified in the standard.